# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 269

Tags: java

I am writing a program that counts the number of words in a text file, but only words that have more than 2 characters in them. It was working fine before, but all of a sudden I am getting an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 269?

Can someone please help?

```
import java.io.*;

class count_words {

    public static int countWords(String str)
    {
        int count = 1, num_of_letters = 0, final_count=1;

        for (int i=0;i<=str.length()-1;i++)
        {
            if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' && str.charAt(i+1)!=' ')
            {
                if(num_of_letters <= 2)
                {
                    count --;
                }

                System.out.println("count is " + num_of_letters);
                num_of_letters = 0;
                count++;
            }
            else if(str.charAt(i) == ',')
            {
                num_of_letters --;
            }
            else
            {
                num_of_letters++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //name of file to open
        String fileName = "/Users/Chris/Desktop/comp 1 McPhee.txt";
        //reference one line at a time
        String line = null;
        int num;

        try 
        {
            //Filereader reads text file in the default encoding.
            FileReader filereader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(filereader);

            while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                num = countWords(line);
                System.out.println(num);
            }
        } 

        //Always close file
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
        }

        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: `charAt(i+1)` is throwing the exception, because `i` is the last index on the last iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of your problem is up here.

```
public static int countWords(String str)
{
  int count = 1, num_of_letters = 0, final_count=1;

  for (int i=0;i<=str.length()-1;i++)
  {
    //This line
    if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' && str.charAt(i+1)!=' ')
```

Because you let i go all the way to str.length()-1, str.charAt(i+1) will exceed the last index position.

For the word "taken"

str.length() = 5;

Index positions 0-4.

When i is 4, src.charAt(i+1) will go for 5.

I think this will solve it.

```
    if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' && ((i+1) < str.length()) && str.charAt(i+1)!=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception because of using str.charAt(i+1) != ' '. If i is 0 and length of the string is 1, i + 1 will try to find element at the position 1 which will throw the exception. You may need to add the condition to check if i is less than (the length of the array -1 ) prior to that.